# Create custom installation process with Electron

Tags: electron, operating-system, desktop

Hello I'm using electron and i have builded a desktop app that allow the user to download other `.exe` files, now the problem is that after `.exe` files are downloaded and executed, installation process it self is handled by the operation system and from there I have no idea how to obtain the selected destination by the user.

Any idea how is possible to take over the installation process via creating custom installer or how to obtain the path to `.exe` that will run the game